# An injection induces a bijection between cosets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I'm self learning algebraic topology and I've come across this proof with some confusion.  In the second to last line, the author says "since the maps are isomorphisms and $p_*$ is an injection, $\Sigma$ induces a bijection between the cosets.

What is the bijection between the cosets that is induced?  Why does the fact that the two maps are isomorphisms and $p_*$ is an injection induce a bijection between these two cosets?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify the notation.  We have groups $G$ and $H$ with subgroups $G_1\subseteq G$ and $H_1\subseteq H$, and an isomorphism $f:G\to H$ such that $f(G_1)=f(H_1)$.  The claim is then that we get a bijection between the cosets of $G_1$ in $G$ and the cosets of $H_1$ and $H$.  But this is obvious: just send a coset $gG_1$ to $f(gG_1)=f(g)H_1$.

In your situation, we have $G=\pi_1(X,x_0)$, $H=\pi_1(X,x_1)$, $G_1=p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0))$, and $H_1=p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_1))$.  The isomorphism $f:G\to H$ is $\sigma$.  The fact that $f(G_1)=H_1$ is immediate from the fact that your diagram commutes and $\Sigma$ is surjective.  Indeed, $$f(G_1)=\sigma(p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0)))=p_*(\Sigma(\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0)))=p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_1))=H_1.$$